# how to merge two different array values

Tags: javascript, jquery

i trying to merge two different array values with ":" separated, but i missed some logic functionality, plz suggest for below scenario.

**Expected to send the value:**

```
35:2:1`45:1:1`45:1:1`45:2:1`45:1:1`34`33`33`34`33`33`34`33`33:1:2`34
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id="cwRow1" class="cwRow">
    <label>Row1:</label>
    <div id="cwCol1" class="cwCol">
        <input type="text" class="width100">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcHeight">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcWidth">
    </div>
    <div id="cwCol2" class="cwCol">
        <input type="text" class="width100">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcHeight">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcWidth">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var totalColumns = $(".width100");
var csvalue = $(".rcWidth, rcHeight");
var svalue = [];
for (var j = 0; j < totalColumns.length; j++) {
    colInput[increm] = parseFloat(totalColumns[0].value);

    for (var j = 0; j < csvalue.length; j++) {
        svalue[increm] = parseFloat(totalColumns[0].value);
        increm++;
    }
    increm++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could include the javascript behind this as well?

Comment: Except from your html code, What have you tried?

Comment: Did you already try some JavaScript code you can show us?

Comment: You should use a standard data structure like JSON instead of that home-grown thing.

Comment: It'd help if you explained what that format meant? (or use a standard on as suggested above). For example you state `35:2:1\`45:1:1` yet all these numbers are on the same row?! I don't really see how your screen shot and HTML are related either?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [jQuery each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on the `cwCol` div as container:

```js
var arr = [];

$('.cwCol').each(function(event ,i){
  var width = $(this).find('.width100').eq(0).val();
  var rcHeight = $(this).find('.rcHeight').eq(0).val();
  var rcWidth = $(this).find('.rcWidth').eq(0).val();
  arr.push(width+":"+rcHeight+":"+rcWidth);
})

console.log(arr.join('`'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cwRow1" class="cwRow">
    <label>Row1:</label>
    <div id="cwCol1" class="cwCol">
        <input type="text" class="width100" value="35">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcHeight" value="1">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcWidth" value="2">
    </div>
    <div id="cwCol2" class="cwCol">
        <input type="text" class="width100" value="45">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcHeight" value="3">
        <input type="number" placeholder="1" class="rcWidth" value="4">
    </div>
</div>
```